# How to produce a Transportation Tableau using tikz matrix

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-matrix

I need a help from you all... I want to produce a Transportation Tableau like the one in the picture using tikz matrix... Is it possible with tikz? If possible please help... Thanks in advance...[image]

Comment: what you try so far?

Comment: I have tried using arrays as I found in one question here itself... But in that the header column and header row entries are coming in center... And using tikz I am planning to draw a matrix with one cell equals to 4 or 9 subcells... So thatI can place the entries at the center of the cells... But is there any shortcut?

Comment: please show what you tried. otherwise your question require service "do-this-instead-of-me" what is not mission of this site.